# Regex Pattern for Variable

Tags: java, regex

I need a general regex pattern for a variable that covers all of the following scenrios:

1. final type variable_name = value, b = value; // final String a = "Hi";
2. type variable_name = value, b; // char a = 'c'
3. variable_name = value; // a = false;
4. type variable_name; // int a;

Variable name cannot start with a digit and if it starts with a _ it must have another letter afterwards.

My regexes in seperate:

1. "(final)\s+" + RESERVED_TYPE_KEYWORDS
           + "\s+(" + VARIABLE_NAME + "\s+=\s+" + VALUE + "|" + VARIABLE_NAME + ")+;"
2. "(" + RESERVED_TYPE_KEYWORDS + VARIABLE_NAME + "(\s+=\s+" + VALUE + "|" + VARIABLE_NAME + ")?)+;"
3. "(" + VARIABLE_NAME + "\s+=\s+" + VALUE + "|" + VARIABLE_NAME + ")+;"
4. RESERVED_TYPE_KEYWORDS + "\s+" + VARIABLE_NAME + "+;"

   RESEREVED_TYPE_KEYWORD = "(int|double|boolean|char|String)"

   VARIABLE_NAME = "(_{1}\w+)|([a-zA-Z]{1}\w*)"

   VALUE = BOOLEAN + "|" + CHAR + "|" + STRING

   BOOLEAN = "(false|true)" + "|" + DOUBLE

   DOUBLE = "(" + INT + "\." + INT + ")" + "|" + "(" + INT + ")"

   INT = "([-]?[1-9]\d*|0)"

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `covers all of the following ..` I see only one scenario i.e, regex for variable_name

Comment: it's a one scenrio but the other things are optional

Comment: You are looking for tokenizer and creating syntax tree not for regex expression.

Comment: No I'm asking for a regex expression that will catch it

Comment: Please identify the place holders in your scenario. Preferrably give the regexes your are using for them. Note, that cannot be just a regex for an identifier, which covers all of them, it must be one regex each. (Then, making the desired regex for a variable is easy.) However while trying to provide those regexes, you will find out what the comment by @MaciejKozieja means.

Comment: I forgot to mention: "Here are my requirements, please write the code for me." is off-topic at StackOverflow.

Comment: making each one in seperate is easy unify all is the hard part.

Comment: I'm coming here after I tried it myself instead of loop around you can just help or you'd better not comment/downvote my post

Comment: Good, I am impressed. Then show the regexes. Provide sample input and desired output, the solution you might get will only cover the sample input you provide. You will soon notice that you did not think of all needed sample input. The flexible solution ... see comment by Maciej.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146934/discussion-between-yunnosch-and-user21312).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is explicitly asking for a tool inapt to provide a solution.

Comment: Please add **all** relevant sample input, i.e. many example lines. Consider the optional presence of newlines in the middle of your patterns. Explain the `{1}`s. Provide the regexes for the new placeholders ("BOOLEAN," "CHAR" , "STRING", too. Consider those potentially being expressions, including calls to functions.

Comment: Edited. _{1} means one _ letter - it's a simple regex syntax

Answer (score 0):

The actual answer is by Maciej Kozieja:
Do not try regexes, use a syntax tree fed by a tokenizer.

I just add some reasoning (quoted from chat by the way),
to help you understand why:

Please understand that what you seem to be trying (find certain parts of the syntax of a programming language) is what I have already tried (with C though).
It does not work just with regexes alone.
You need to apply all kinds of context knowledge.
That gets you a syntax-tree.
In order to feed a syntax-tree a practically unavoidable method is the tokenizer.

On the other hand, I am less sarcastic than it might admittedly seem.
If you get the regexes for **all** the placeholders, you will probably be able to cover your variable scenarious yourself.
Finding those regexes (I admittedly assumed) will require the context-awareness I associate with a syntax tree.

But if you are only parsing very repetitive code, boringly similar all the time, you might be able to make a lot of assumptions, which in turn allow you to actually get along with regexes.
(I have done that, too - and even successfully. But I should mention I was only successful after many painful iterations of "Oh, I forgot that special case." If had to do the same work again, I would probably start with tokenizer feed a syntax-tree. Or look for something doing that for me, via my favorite search engine.)
For this it is however extremely important to be aware of **all** possible input, and for any chance of getting a solution here, you would have to provide all that sample input.

That case (regexes based on many assumptions) is also covered by you giving the regexes for the placeholders, because that defines the scope of flexibility you allow.
However, just from one person who got burned by those assumptions to one who probably will be: You really have to think of all possibilities in your sample input.